# convert a string from a list to a float

Tags: python

I have a list with strings. Some of the strings contain alphabets and some contain numbers. I want to convert one of the strings with numbers in it to a float but getting an error

the list is called `x`. the 3rd element of the list is numbers. I tried `x[2] = float (x[2])` but it gives me `:Value error: could not convert string to a float:%"`
See line 12 of the code where I am comparing `float(x[2])` with `100`

```
def file_read(fname):
    i = 0
    content_array = []
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        #Content_list is the list that contains the read lines.     

        for line in f:
            content_array.append(line)
            x = content_array[i].split('|')
            i = i + 1
            x[2] = x[2].strip() # to delete any empty spaces
            if float(x[2]) > 50.00:
                print ('got one')
        print x[2]
        print i

file_read('flow.txt')
```

Comment: can you share a sample of the list?

Comment: `content_array.append(line)` why do you append list firstly and then get value from it by index?

Comment: You can debug your code by e.g printing x[2] before the if. The error message indicates that x[2] contains the char %

Comment: BASE CASE|31 FINCAST7    138.00    269 BURDETT7    138.00 12|51.95|44.57|0.00|85.09|85.09|1                      This is sample line from flow.txt file

Comment: There is no % sign in the string x[2]. I printed it already

Comment: The sample you gave does not raise an error, you could as suggested by @Ely Fialkoff use try / except and print in the except block the line that raised the exception

Comment: This code works fine using your sample line. It might be a case that one of the lines has the character `%` in it. For example sometimes when you copy some data from an html response spaces are replaced with `%20` or other characters are replaces similarly. So, just check your data carefully and add a `try-except` statement to find where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Around your `if` statement you can wrap a `try/except` block, the program will `try` to convert `float(x[2])` to a float, but if it cannot (since its a string) it will execute the `except` portion of the code.

```
try:
    if float(x[2]) > 50.0:
        print('got one')
except:
    # do something else, if x[2] is not a float
    pass     # if you don't want to do anything.
```

Comment: Specify except ValueError: to catch only the error raised by float( ). Not important in this code, but good practice when using try/except to avoid catching unexpected exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to check if it's a number, and then you can safely cast it to float.

```
import re
rgx = "^\d*\.?\d*$"
if re.match(rgx, x):
    print("it's a number!")
    x = float(x)
```

Comment: Your regex works only for decimal notation : " -1.6e+3 " would not match even if it is recognized by float(). I recommend using float () in a try/except ValueError

Comment: @Nico237 True, I didn't consider those kind of floats because of the sample given, my fault.